# How to append jquery autocomplete to a dynamically changed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the below textbox and autocomplete script, which currently work as expected:

HTML:

```
<div id="partNameCont">
     <input type='text' name="part_name" id="part_name">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var autocomp    =   jQuery.noConflict();
    autocomp(document).ready(function() {

        autocomp('#part_name').autocomplete({
            source: "test.php",
            select: function(e, ui) {
                var tmp = ui.item.label;
                ui.item.label = ui.item.value;
                ui.item.value = tmp; 
                getPartCategory(ui.item.label);
            },
            open: function (e, ui) {
                var acData = autocomp(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
                acData.menu.element.find('li').each(function () {
                    var me = autocomp(this);
                    var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
                    me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b><span style="color:#E7930D;">$1</span></b>'));
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is that I want to set `part_name` to `disabled` on page load. Then make it available again when the user selects value for another select box.

So I have this on page load:

```
<div id="partNameCont">
     <input name="" type="text" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

However, when the user selects the required select box and I change the `partNameCont` back to its original content, the autocomplete does not work.

**UPDATE**: This is the function I use the update the `partNameCont` - I update the entire `div` not only the `input` element:

```
function getPartName(id) {      
    var autonew_id1 =   jQuery.noConflict();
    autonew_id1.ajax({
       url: "getPartName.php",
       data: "id="+id,
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){
          autonew_id1('#partNameCont').html('');
          autonew_id1('#partNameCont').html(data);
       }
   });  
}
```

And my new data for `partNameCont` is this:

```
<input type="text" name="part_name" id="part_name" class="text-input ui-autocomplete-input" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Any suggestions what modification should be done to the function to make it work with dynamically changed element?

Comment: I checked all those, but they all deal with dynamically adding additional fields + 1,2,3 fields, which is different from what I need.

Comment: Besides, those examples deal with updating the very element, while I use ajax to update the entire `div` where the element is contained - hence my problems with getting this to work the right way.

Comment: so you want to turn on and off the "autocomplete" attribute? If so, you can use .prop("autocomplete",true) to activate it and .prop("autocomplete",false) to turn it off.